# Retrieve the CSS value using Selenium

Tags: selenium

CSS style sheet:

`background: url("/olam/images/brand30/usage_meter/green-vertical.png") repeat-x scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);`

I want to retrieve the URL, tried using below :

```
String cssValue = driver.findelement(by.xpath).getCssValue("background");
System.out.println(driver.findelement(by.xpath).getCssValue("background"));
```

Still unable to retrieve the background value, i am getting Null value.

Comment: Do you have the page link? Will try to write it up then.

Answer (score 1):

[`background`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/colors.html#propdef-background) is a [*shorthand* property](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/REC-CSS2-20110607/about.html#shorthand). It's really just a convenient way of writing a bunch of real properties.

[According to the JavaDoc](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue(java.lang.String)), `getCssValue()` cannot retrieve shorthand properties. you have to ask for the individual properties, like `background-image` and `background-color`.